# GPU control using CUDA in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I want to use Tensorflow-gpu in Python.
My PC has two GPUs. (GPU-A and GPU-B)

I want to specify the GPU to be used.

So when I run the program, I used the following command:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 1
```

The GPU to be used can be specified according to the value.
Specifically, it was assigned as follows.

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0
```

I was able to use GPU-B.

On the other hand

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 1
```

At that time, I was able to use GPU-A.

However, I cannot know in advance whether GPU-A or GPU-B corresponds to the value 0 or 1.
I found a statement that "this index is assigned in descending order of computing power".
However, GPU-A can calculate faster than GPU-B.
I think that "indexes are assigned in order of the revision number (Compute Capability), not the calculation speed".
In fact, GPU-B has higher compute capability than GPU-A.

If the hypothesis is correct, I have another question.
If multiple GPUs with the same Compute Capability are used, how will they be assigned?

Answer (score 1):

You can try running `nvidia-smi` in your terminal. The output you get shows you GPU ordering. For example:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.104      Driver Version: 410.104      CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   52C    P8    21W / 250W |      2MiB / 11176MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GT 1030     Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 41%   54C    P0    N/A /  30W |   1055MiB /  2001MiB |      6%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Here, I have 2 GPUs:

1. GPU 0: GTX 1080Ti
2. GPU 1: GT 1030

You can then further use indexes in `TensorFlow`.

Comment: I ran “nvidia-smi” and checked the output.
It showed that GPU-A is GPU-0 and GPU-B is GPU-1.
But, when I use the following command,
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 0
, the used GPU was GPU-B.

I think that index assignment is different between nvidia-smi and Python execution.

Comment: The index assignment (by default) may vary between `nvidia-smi` and CUDA.  This is covered in various questions here on the `cuda` SO tag.

Comment: Acorrdint to [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/815835/different-index-definition-in-nvml-amp-cuda-runtime-/) official answer `You can also use the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable along with the nvml/(driver) ordering to parcel out GPUs programmatically.`. @Tine could you show us how exactly are u using `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES `?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for answering.
I understand how the index is assigned differently depending on the CUDA used. If you want to specify a specific GPU accurately using programming, you need to devise ways such as acquiring device information.
Thank you again.